# Is it possible to do a PhD in Environmental Policy and Economics if I do not have an academic background in Economics?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, changing-fields, economics

Is it possible to do a PhD in Environmental Policy and Economics if I do not have an academic background in Economics (except for two papers in my graduate prog. one on Environmental economics and the other on Resource Economics which, I feel were very watered down)? I have an Graduate degree in Environmental Studies and undergraduate degrees in Biotechnology and Law. I am very interested in pursing a PhD involving Environmental Policy; and Economics I feel is an integral part of the discourse.
What can I do to overcome my lack of a degree/ course on Economics in my academics career so far? Will writing papers that uses Economic theories and concepts help me in getting accepted for a PhD position?
Will I have to pursue another graduate degree in Economics?
I am from India, where education is very compartmentalized and not generally interdisciplinary or multidisciplinary (with few exceptions).

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can. However make sure your supervisor(s) know the economics better (e.g., by looking at his/her current publications) than you. This is because if the supervisor doesn't know the area very well, he/she doesn't know if your work is in fact a contribution because he is not an experienced yet; and therefore it will create a very unpleasant situation in which you work hard; without knowing you are on the right track.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. 
I have a follow-up question. To be accepted by a supervisor, won't I have to exhibit some competencies in Economics ? Or are most supervisors open to accepting students from even outside their core disciple, like in my case?

Comment: @lyn.irene I met many friends of mine that went from Mathematics to Computer Science-based Ph.Ds or visa versa. In fact you might have a better chance at getting a Ph.D. position from an Academic in the area of Economics because then he/she can contribute with you in both fields; and therefore by accepting you, his/her research resume will cover more grounds. Think about it this way: the supervisor already knows economics, so he is already active in this domain, and so he/she wants to expand on his research contributions for future promotions.